# ReadyApi Property Transfer counting elements in JSON array response

Tags: ready-api

On the Transfer Property page, how do I set a property which contains the count of the number of elements in a JSON array response?

e.g.

JSON response:
[
{
"category": "XXX",
"other": "YYY",
"another": "ZZZ"
},
{
"category": "XXX",
"other": "YYY"  ,
"another": "ZZZ"
}
]

I am using JSON Path,
and have an expression as follows:
$[?(@.category == 'XXX')].length()

property -> [[3, 3]]

I require a count property to be set to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONPath has very sketchy support for any functions, certainly in ReadyAPI/SoapUI.

You could use Property: ResponseAsXml, and use the XPath `count()` function. So the expression will likely be `count(//category='XXX')`